# What is this group $G=\langle a,b,c\mid a^2=1, b^2=1, c^2=ab\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider the group presentation $$G=\langle a,b,c\mid a^2=1, b^2=1, c^2=ab\rangle.$$

Is this a known group? What is $G$ isomorphic to?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It reminds me of a [triangle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group).

Comment: One can eliminate $b$: $$G\cong\langle a,c\mid a^2, (c^2a^{-1})^2\rangle.$$ Presentations whose relators are proper powers of some words are widely studied . . .

Comment: Sorry: $$G\cong\langle a,c\mid a^2, (a^{-1}c^2)^2\rangle.$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about "known groups". I can answer questions about its properties.

For example it is virtually abelian: the subgroup $H = \langle ab, cac^{-1}a \rangle$ is free abelian and normal in $G$ with $G/H \cong C_2^2$.

You can see directly from the presentation that the subgroup $\langle ab \rangle$ is normal with quotient group the infinite dihedral group generated by the images of $a$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on $$G\cong\langle a,c\mid a^2, (a^{-1}c^2)^2\rangle,$$ we have

$$\begin{align}
G&\cong\langle a, c\mid a^2, ac^2a^{-1}=c^{-2}\rangle \\
&\cong \boxed{BS(2,-2)/\Bbb Z_2},
\end{align}$$

where $BS(2,-2)$ is a [Baumslag–Solitar group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group) and the normal subgroup $\Bbb Z_2$ is generated by $a$.